# must retrieve the list from the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

it is such that I have to get something out of my content from the database and shown off, this is how I have two paragraphs which I should have shown up.

it looks like this in my **model** -> **undervisning.cs**

```
public class Undervisning
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

it looks like this in my **controllers** -> **undervisningcontroller.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DatabaseClasseDataContext db = new DatabaseClasseDataContext();

    Undervisning newundervisning = new Undervisning();
    newundervisning.Name = db.Packages.ToList().ToString();

    return View(newundervisning);
}
```

It is such that I have to have it to be shown here **index.cshtml**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="plan">
      <h3>Enterprise<span>$59</span></h3>
       <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem is such that I stuck to how to pull content from the list and be where it should be, as I said I have to use what we have in .cshtml 2 once and maybe more with time.

Comment: What is `Packages` from your dbContext?

Comment: what u mean @brroshan

Comment: You just want to show the name?

Answer (score 0):

undervisningcontroller.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        DatabaseClasseDataContext db = new DatabaseClasseDataContext();
        var model=db.Packages.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

index.cshtml:

```
   @foreach(var u in Model)
    {
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="plan">
          <h3>@u.Name<span>$@u.Price</span></h3>
           <p>@u.Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Comment: Its make error on `foreach` -> error : Compilation Error. and its will only take Tostring on my list.