# Causing problems with foreach into my mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach

This is how I have made a previous post as you can see here.

[must retrieve the list from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492512/must-retrieve-the-list-from-the-database?noredirect=1#comment50968434_31492512)

I have tried to make my foreach which have been previously described. but it causes problems for not running my foreach in through while making the mistake on it.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@foreach (var u in Model)
 {
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <div class="plan">
          <h3>@u.Name<span>$@u.Price</span></h3>
          <p>@u.Text</p>
       </div>
    </div>
 }
```

and **undervisningController.cs**

```
// GET: Undervisning
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        DatabaseClasseDataContext db = new DatabaseClasseDataContext();

        var model = db.Packages.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

And the top on index.cshtml have i:

```
@model MentorOrdblind_MVC.Models.Undervisning.Undervisning
```

Model **Undervisning.cs**

```
public class Undervisning
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: `@model ....Undervisning` suggest a single object, not a collection so you cant iterate over it. What error do you get?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Try to describe the problem, do you get any error description or exception?

Comment: @StephenMuecke OP can iterate over it, if `Undervisning` implement `IEnumerable`

Comment: Please explain what you mean by _"it causes problems for not running my foreach in through while making the mistake on it"_. What do you expect to happen, what does actually happen and what have you tried to make those two match?

Comment: @CodeCaster : I recorded what kind of data type it is and add the edit.

Comment: You need to add the exact error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing your view a `List<T>` but your model is not a type of `IEnumerable`. So your view is only expecting a single object of the type `Undervisning` and not a collection.

Use this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MentorOrdblind_MVC.Models.Undervisning.Undervisning>
```

Comment: @Grundy I am not following. The View is only expecting one object and not a collection. If the properties inside `Undervisning` are collections then we should see the model to help answer. calling `Packages.ToList()` and directly assigning that to the model, implies that it is a collection and not a single object.

Comment: if class `Undervisning` implement `IEnumerable`, then one object is equal collection and can be iterable with `foreach`

Comment: @Grundy This line of the code `var model = db.Packages.ToList();` is directly implying that model is now a `List<T>` So if `Undervisning` is a type of `IEnumerable` then he now has a `List<IEnumerable<T>>`. Which means his View will still need to have the `IEnumerable` declaration.

Comment: now its giv me a error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Comment: @JesperPetersen ok use `@model List<MentorOrdblind_MVC.Models.Undervisning.Undervisning>` but that shouldn't matter. What is the full error with the inner message?

Comment: probably he passing list of object in a different type :)

Comment: @PawelMaga Yes, does seem to be the case. This question is hopeless. I suggest that Jesper does some reading up on the basics...

Comment: @JamieRees sits error are: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MentorOrdblind_MVC.Models.Linq.Package]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MentorOrdblind_MVC.Models.Undervisning.Undervisning]'.

Comment: @JesperPetersen There is your answer. You are passing the View a `Package` when the view wants a `undervisning`.

Comment: I recorded what kind of data type it is and add the edit.

Comment: @JesperPetersen You are passing the type of `Package` to the view. `var model = db.Packages.ToList();` returns a type of `Package` and not `Undervisning`. You need to convert your Package results to a object of `Undervisning` to use it on the View

Comment: @JamieRees Okay, but how do I do when I'm nice new to MVC. Sorry

Comment: @JesperPetersen Please post your `Package` class in your original question. I will then update my answer.

Comment: @JamieRees you think of my database?

Answer (score 0):

Change your model delcaration to:

```
@model IEnumerable<MentorOrdblind_MVC.Models.Undervisning.Undervisning>
```

At this moment your model is a single class, not a list of objects

Comment: but possibly `Undervisning` class implement `IEnumerable` :-)

Comment: This line  var model = db.Packages.ToList(); says directly that the model is the list

Comment: now its giv me a error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Comment: This error clearly says what is the problem. You have not shared information about the structure of your type so we will not guess what's wrong.

Comment: I recorded what kind of data type it is and add the edit.

Comment: We need also information about the db.Packages (what type of objects?) Its also Undervisning?

Answer (score 0):

Always keep in mind what is being passed from controller action to view. If you pass only model from the action then use the model reference in the respective view of the action. If you pass List then use IEnumerable model reference in the view.

```
If you pass list from action then in the view use:
@model IEnumerable<your model> in the top as reference
If you pass model without a list then use:
@model your model
```

In your case you are passing list so use IEnumerable of your desired model class.

Thanks